# how to send ajax request in magento 2 by using ajax request inside a javascript function?

Tags: magento2

I want to send ajax request in javascript function. how to send the ajax request calling a javascript function in magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me in the phtml file

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/Frontname/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: {param:6},
    showLoader: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

This code will use Ajax with "POST" Method and send param=6 as a parameter,

You need only to put your parameters and change the URL.